# Qt ItemDelegate displayText() with a QTableWidget: How can I access the table index?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

I display data in a QTableWidget in various number formats, depending on the setting of a combobox (outside QTableWidget). This works nicely by redefining the `displayText()` method of an ItemDelegate.

I would also like to style / modify the displayed text depending on its index, however, only the text and the locale are passed as arguments to `displayText()`.

As a workaround I also redefined the `paint()` method because here the index is passed as well. This seems very clumsy to me and I'm also at the end of the rope when I start styling the text - pure Cargo Cult programming ...

So, am I barking up the wrong tree? Is there a simpler way to format e.g. only the element (0,1) (see code below), maybe within `displayText()`?

The following code is just a minimum working example, full code under

https://github.com/chipmuenk/pyFDA/blob/coeff_table/pyfda/input_widgets/filter_coeffs.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function, division, unicode_literals, absolute_import
#from PyQt4.QtGui import  ...
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QTableWidget, 
                             QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QStyledItemDelegate)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyle  
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
#from PyQt4.QtGui import QStyle, QFont
import numpy as np

class ItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    """
    The following methods are subclassed to replace display and editor of the
    QTableWidget.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """
        Pass instance `parent` of parent class (TestTable)
        """
        super(ItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent # instance of the parent (not the base) class

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        """
        painter:  instance of QPainter
        option: instance of QStyleOptionViewItem(V4?)
        index:   instance of QModelIndex
        """
        style_option = option
        # read text to be shown:
        if index.row() == 0 and index.column() == 1: # always display "1!" at index (0,1)
            style_option.text = "1!" 
            style_option.font.setBold(True)
            # now paint the cell
            self.parent.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, style_option, painter)
        else:
            super(ItemDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index) # default painter

    def displayText(self, text, locale):
        """
        Display `text` in the selected with the selected number
        of digits

        text:   string / QVariant from QTableWidget to be rendered
        locale: locale for the text
        """ 
        data = text # .toString() # Python 2: need to convert to "normal" string
        return "{0:>{1}}".format(data, 4)


class TestTable(QWidget):
    """ Create widget for viewing / editing / entering data """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TestTable, self).__init__(parent)

        self.bfont = QFont()
        self.bfont.setBold(True)

        self.tblCoeff = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tblCoeff.setItemDelegate(ItemDelegate(self))

        layVMain = QVBoxLayout()
        layVMain.addWidget(self.tblCoeff)
        self.setLayout(layVMain)

        self.ba = np.random.randn(3,4) # test data
        self._refresh_table()

    def _refresh_table(self):
        """ (Re-)Create the displayed table from self.ba """
        num_cols = 3
        num_rows = 4

        self.tblCoeff.setRowCount(num_rows)
        self.tblCoeff.setColumnCount(num_cols)

        for col in range(num_cols):
            for row in range(num_rows):
                # set table item from self.ba 
                item = self.tblCoeff.item(row, col)
                if item: # does item exist?
                    item.setText(str(self.ba[col][row]))
                else: # no, construct it:
                    self.tblCoeff.setItem(row,col,QTableWidgetItem(
                          str(self.ba[col][row])))

        self.tblCoeff.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tblCoeff.resizeRowsToContents()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainw = TestTable(None)

    app.setActiveWindow(mainw)
    mainw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT: =================================================================

@m7913d's suggestion works for me, I'm overriding the initStyleOption()  method instead of the paint() method which looks more concise to me. This is the updated code (so I've partially answered my own question):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function, division, unicode_literals, absolute_import
#from PyQt4.QtGui import  ...
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QTableWidget, 
                             QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QStyledItemDelegate)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyle  
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
#from PyQt4.QtGui import QStyle, QFont
import numpy as np

class ItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    """
    The following methods are subclassed to replace display and editor of the
    QTableWidget.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """
        Pass instance `parent` of parent class (TestTable)
        """
        super(ItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent # instance of the parent (not the base) class

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        """
        Initialize `option` with the values using the `index` index. When the 
        item (0,1) is processed, it is styled especially. All other items are 
        passed to the original `initStyleOption()` which then calls `displayText()`.
        """
        if index.row() == 0 and index.column() == 1: # a[0]: always 1
            option.text = "1!" # QString object
            option.font.setBold(True) 
            option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignRight
            #option.backgroundBrush ...
        else:
            # continue with the original `initStyleOption()`
            super(ItemDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)     

    def displayText(self, text, locale):
        """
        Display `text` in the selected with the selected number
        of digits

        text:   string / QVariant from QTableWidget to be rendered
        locale: locale for the text
        """ 
        data = text # .toString() # Python 2: need to convert to "normal" string
        return "{0:>{1}}".format(data, 4)


class TestTable(QWidget):
    """ Create widget for viewing / editing / entering data """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TestTable, self).__init__(parent)

        self.bfont = QFont()
        self.bfont.setBold(True)

        self.tblCoeff = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tblCoeff.setItemDelegate(ItemDelegate(self))

        layVMain = QVBoxLayout()
        layVMain.addWidget(self.tblCoeff)
        self.setLayout(layVMain)

        self.ba = np.random.randn(3,4) # test data
        self._refresh_table()

    def _refresh_table(self):
        """ (Re-)Create the displayed table from self.ba """
        num_cols = 3
        num_rows = 4

        self.tblCoeff.setRowCount(num_rows)
        self.tblCoeff.setColumnCount(num_cols)

        for col in range(num_cols):
            for row in range(num_rows):
                # set table item from self.ba 
                item = self.tblCoeff.item(row, col)
                if item: # does item exist?
                    item.setText(str(self.ba[col][row]))
                else: # no, construct it:
                    self.tblCoeff.setItem(row,col,QTableWidgetItem(
                          str(self.ba[col][row])))

        self.tblCoeff.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tblCoeff.resizeRowsToContents()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainw = TestTable(None)

    app.setActiveWindow(mainw)
    mainw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

replaces the overridden paint routine and is more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to override [`QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) and set the [`text`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qstyleoptionviewitem.html#text-var) yourself as this is now [done by qt](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs-1/blob/master/src/qt/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp#L409):

> ```
> option->text = displayText(value, option->locale);
> ```

Comment: Thanx, I've added your suggestion to the original question above. Unfortunately I'm still riddled by what is probably my real problem: I don't understand how QStyleOptionViewItem works, to me its Qt documentation is even more cryptic than the rest. Could you give me a starting point how to actually style the item? I found the attributes (?) `text` and `font` more or less by chance but I've no idea how to set e.g. the text alignment, its text and background color.

Comment: [The documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qstyleoptionviewitem.html#public-variables) gives an overview of all the different properties you can set, including `backgroundBrush` and `displayAlignment`.